# Symfony2 structural composite pattern with entities

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, composite

I am trying to implement a simple menu composite pattern.

These are the following classes i came up with.

MenuItem:

```
namespace MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Entity;


use MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Menu\MenuComponent;

class MenuItem implements MenuComponent
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $path;
    private $parent;
    private $visible;
    private $createdOn;
    private $templating;
    private $attr;
    private $children;
    private $website;
    private $position = 1;

    public function __construct($name = null, $path = null, $attr = array(), $visible = true)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->visible = $visible;
        $this->attr = $attr;

        $this->createdOn = new \DateTime;
    }

    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->createdOn = new \DateTime;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        $data['menu_item'] = $this;

        $data['options'] = $this->attr;

        if($this->hasChildren())
            return $this->templating->render('MYBUNDLE:Menu:menu_dropdown.html.twig', $data);

        if($this->isChild())
            return $this->parent->getTemplating()->render('MYBUNDLE:Menu:menu_item.html.twig', $data);

        return $this->templating->render('MYBUNDLE:Menu:menu_item.html.twig', $data);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setTemplating($templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isChild()
    {
        return $this->hasParent();
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasParent()
    {
        return isset($this->parent);
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return count($this->children) > 0;
    }
}
```

If left out the getters and setters to make it a bit shorter here.
As you can see this is the entity and it contains a build() function, however this function uses the render method which in my opinion shouldn't be in an entity.

MenuController

```
<?php
namespace MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Controller;


use MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Menu\Menu;
use MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Entity\MenuItem;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function generateAction()
    {
        $menu = new Menu($this->get('templating'));

        // load menu items
        $items = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MYBUNDLE:MenuItem')->findOrdered();

        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if(!$item->hasParent())
                $menu->add($item);
        }
        return new Response($menu->build());
    }
}
```

The MenuController gets called to render the menu:

```
{{ render(controller('MYBUNDLE:Menu:generate')) }}
```

I would also like this to be different since it doesn't look right. Perhaps it's better to create a twig function to render the menu?

MenuComponent:

```
namespace MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Menu;


interface MenuComponent {
    public function build();
}
```

Menu:

```
namespace MYNAME\MYBUNDLE\Menu;


class Menu implements MenuComponent
{
    private $children;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct($templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function add(MenuComponent $component)
    {
        $component->setTemplating($this->templating);
        $this->children[] = $component;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->templating->render('MYBUNDLE:Menu:menu.html.twig', array("menu_items" => $this->children));
    }
}
```

Menu Contains the MenuComponents and will render the menu first, in each MenuItem it's build() method is called.

I think it's better to remove the rendering logic from my MenuItem entity and place this somewhere else, however i can't figure out on how to do this properly within this design pattern.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise or are you trying to create a complete reusable menu generation system? If it is the latter, you should take a look at the `KnpMenuBundle` (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) as it may be helpful.

Comment: It is a learning exercise :)